# I have an offline SQLite database, I want to make it online and work with it

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sqlite

In my android studio project, I created an offline SQLite database, that stores data in the user's phone. But right now, I want to make this database online, so everyone who has the app can work with one database (If the first user changes the data, the data will change in second user's application). How I can make my existing database online, so several people can work with it? (Do I need to create a new database using PHP script?)

Here is some of my Database class code:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mylist7641337.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mylist_data7641337";
public static final String COL1 = "ID";
public static final String COL2 = "NAME1";
public static final String COL3 = "YEAR1";
public static final String COL4= "MONTH1";
public static final String COL5= "DAY1";
public static final String COL6= "PRICE1";
public static final String COL7= "STYEAR1";
public static final String COL8= "STMONTH1";
public static final String COL9= "STDAY1";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            +"NAME1 TEXT, "
            +"YEAR1 INTEGER, "
            +"MONTH1 INTEGER, "
            +"DAY1 INTEGER, "
            +"PRICE1 INTEGER, "
            +"STYEAR1 INTEGER, "
            +"STMONTH1 INTEGER, "
            +"STDAY1 INTEGER)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the default Android database is `SQLite`. It is an embedded DBMS. `SQLite` is not a client–server database engine.

**TL,DR** You cannot provide access to the local database on your device.

The most common way to interact with the backend is to create a REST API/JSON RPC/... and query the backend server for data.

On the backend side, you may have any DBMS you need, but end clients will be abstracted from these details via API.

Of course you can query a database server directly using `MySQL, PostgreSQL,...` drivers but that is not recommended.

So all in all, you can keep your local data stored in the local database and periodically upload data to the server or you can just interact with the backend without caching data locally. In the latter case, you will be always in-sync.

Hope I explained the matter.